# How to get the bash output to a variable and hide output afterwards in python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am trying to get the `bash` output to a variable and then `hide` the output afterwards in the command itself.

I could find a way to hide the output using `/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the command like below:

```
kubectl get deployments -n kube-system | grep minions /dev/null 2>&1
```

It hides the output, but I need to get its output to a variable and then hide it (**so I will still have the output but command wouldn't show the output in terminal**)

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
import subprocess

cmd = "kubectl get deployments -n kube-system | grep minions"
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: I am actually executing this bash command using `python`. So how can I do this with python?

Comment: Why python is never mentioned in your post ?

Comment: Are you sure this method wouldn't print the output to the terminal?

Comment: Are you sure this method wouldn't print the output to the terminal?  This `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: yes. I tested and it doesn't recognize the `grep` with `|`. This is my command - `["kubectl", "get", "deployments", "-n", constants.NAMESPACE, "|", "grep", "-E", "'(^|\s)"+constants.DEPLOYMENT_NAME+"($|\s)'"]`

Answer (score -1):

Look up backquotes in bash.  They capture the output of a command without it appearing to the user.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: No, backquotes are deprecated by `$( )`

Comment: And the ABS is not a great reference to cite.

Comment: I agree, ABS is outdated too